# How to investigate active MySQL transactions that are not visible in processlist?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, innodb, hikaricp

We have a Java application that works with MariaDB 10.4.28 hosted in AWS RDS.

We have a situation that application went down with reason "CannotCreateTransactionException". The pool has 40 active connections and 0 idle connections.

We have several tools that fire at such moments to help debug such situations:

- ThreadStackDump

  - The dump shows that there are no actual threads running any queries at all, all threads are waiting for a connection from a pool.
- "show processlist"

  - It shows no queries running except just a couple normal ones that are not hanged and finish within milliseconds
- "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"

  - It in fact shows a lot of records like the following

```
---TRANSACTION 2974372519, ACTIVE 31 sec
  2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 4
```

Questions:

- What can be a command or an approach to understand that this 2974372519 transaction is, what it is attempting to do?
- What can be an approach to understand what my 40 occupied DB pool connections are doing?

We use HikariCP:4.0.3 and mysql-connector-java:8.0.22.

Comment: Is your code correctly closing connections when you're done with them? Because that is what returns them to the connection pool for reuse.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel indeed. The app is in production for years, we are very far away from v0.1-style mistakes. This version of app works under heavy load for days in other environments.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel though I will double-check this.

Comment: Perhaps "CannotCreateTransactionException" is caused by running out of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are stored in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX. To find the statement, just execute

```
SELECT trx_query FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE trx_id=2974372519;
```

See also: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-innodb_trx-table/)